# Reusing ASIO connection, read_some exception

Tags: http, boost, network-programming, boost-asio, http-1.0

I am currently trying to figure out how to properly reuse an asio socket.  I am able to successfully send out a request, and get the result.  The second time I send out a request, I get an exception: read_some: End of file.  The second write seems to work fine, I see the second http request going out over wireshark.  I am thinking that there is left over information on the socket that is corrupting my connection in some way.  Any help would be appreciated with this issue.  Here is the code I am using:

```
persistent_connection::persistent_connection(std::string ip, std::string port):
io_service_(), socket_(io_service_), is_setup_(false)
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service_);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(ip,port);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *iterator;
    socket_.async_connect(endpoint, boost::bind(&persistent_connection::handler_connect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, iterator));
    io_service_.run();
}


void persistent_connection::handler_connect(const boost::system::error_code &ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
{
    if(ec)
    {
        std::cout << "Couldn't connect" << ec << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        boost::asio::socket_base::keep_alive keep_option(true);
        socket_.set_option(keep_option);
    }
}


void persistent_connection::write(std::string message)
{
    std::string request_stream = "GET /" + message + " HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    request_stream += "HOST: 10.1.10.220";
    request_stream += "Accept: */*\r\n";
    request_stream += "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";

    try
    {
        boost::asio::write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(request_stream, request_stream.size()));
    }catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Write exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    boost::array<char,8192> buf;
    try
    {
        socket_.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf));
    }catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Read exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    std::string response = buf.data();
    std::cout << response << std::endl;
}
```

Edit: Added main function.

```
int main()
{
    persistent_connection p("10.1.10.220", "80");
    std::string check;
    do
    {
        std::cin >> check;
        if(check.compare("s") == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Sending" << std::endl;
            p.write("100");
        }
    }while(check.compare("x") != 0);
}
```

Comment: It's not quite clear how you use the above code. Where does the "first time" end, and where does the "second time" begin? Are you sure that the peer doesn't close the connection after the first time?

Comment: Sorry, left that part out.  Basically the first time write is called, everything runs fine.  The next time I try and use write, I get a read exception.

Comment: This means that the http server closes the connection after the first request is completed, i.e. it doesn't honor "Connection: keep-alive" header. When you get the first response, do you see "Connection: keep-alive" header? Did you try to request "HTTP/1.1"?

Comment: Thank you, it seems the server I was testing with did not support keep alive, and that was the problem.

Comment: but try requesting HTTP/1.1 - this version supports keep-alive by default.

Comment: ok, then I'll put this as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact you get this exception when trying to `read_some` means that the HTTP server closes the connection after the first request is over, i.e. the server ignores "Connection: keep-alive" header (note that HTTP 1.0 servers don't necessarily support persistent connections).

However, in 1.1 version connections are [persistent by default](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-8.1), so requesting "HTTP/1.1" should solve this issue.